# При переносе сайта на хостинг не работают стили, скрипты и не грузятся картинки. Один HTML

Tags: хостинг

Вот так выглядит мой head:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Через ОСПанель все работает прекрасно. Раньше уже выкладывал на хостинг сайты, пути указывал так же.
Браузер ругается таким текстом: "portrait.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: Права на файлы не принадлежат вэб серверу. Chmod-ните там что-нибудь

Comment: Да, оказалось, что не было прав у файлов.

Comment: а то ;) сервер об этом и сказал